# Anchor for insulated double plasterboard

Tags: drywall-anchor

I have 20mm previously drilled holes in double thickness insulated plasterboard.

I think a toggle bolt will be the most appropriate, but I’m struggling to find something that will be appropriate given the thickness of the wall and the insulation.

Any recommendations welcome!

Edit: I’m hanging a 12.5kg mirror, but the large holes are already there.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you're trying to hang and the weight?

Answer (score 1):

[These toggler anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-30-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183849) will work for thin to very thick walls.

You do not say what the insulation is, The insulation may be a factor in getting them to toggle into place properly. I sometimes use a wire to push fiberglall insulation aside a little so they sit properly.

I have posted several answers about installing these anchors read a few for info and tip/tricks.

https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A56737+toggler

Answer (score 0):

use the nut of a toggle bolt but substitute threaded rod (or a longer machine screw) for the screw part.

Comment: Hi. Your answers keep popping up on the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. Would you mind capitalizing, and even add a second or third sentence? Thanks.